# Can't see console.log() in Linux terminal

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-ec2

I'm running node.js on my Linux  EC2 Instance but I'm not able to see logs when I refresh my homepage.

```
client.connect()
.then(function () {
    return client.execute('SELECT * FROM test_keyspace.users');
})
.then(function (result) {
    const row = result.rows[0];
    console.log('Obtained row: ', row);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.error('There was an error when connecting', err);
    return client.shutdown().then(() => { throw err; });
});
```

How do I get the logs?

edit: running through pm2

Comment: how are you running your node.js application???Through pm2??

Comment: @Subburaj yes through pm2

Comment: Ah that was my issue didn't think of it, I need to do pm2 logs. Can you post it below so I can mark your answer correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
pm2 logs
```

to see the all latest logs